# Is there a name for sets $S$ where every $x\in\mathcal{P}(S)$ is totally ordered except $S$ itself?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I'm in a situation where it's useful to think of any subset of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ as being totally ordered (under the order "inherited" from $\mathbb{Z}$). Of course, finite fields can't be totally ordered themselves, which makes we wonder:

Is there a name for sets where every subset (but the set itself) is totally ordered, and the set itself has no notion of order whatsoever? Can such sets even exist?

Comment: It is entirely possible to totally order a finite field; the order just won't be compatible with the field operations -- but that is no worse than the ordering you want to inherit to _subsets_ of the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S$ has more than three elements, and the total orders on subsets are compatible, then we can build a total order on the entire set by $a\leq b$ in $S$ iff $a\leq b$ in $\{a,b\}$.

This could fail the transitive property if $|S|=3$, since it would then be entirely possible to have $a\leq b\leq c\leq a$.

Of course, this ordering need have nothing to do with any structure on the  set, and definitely won't respect the operations in a finite field the way the canonical order on any subfield of the reals does.

Comment: Ahh, so does that mean every proper subset being totally ordered (under compatible orders) doesn't imply the whole set is totally ordered (under a compatible order), even if $|S|>3$, but, rather, we need the condition you specify?

Comment: Every proper subset being totally ordered under compatible orders IS the condition I specified.

Comment: In fact, "all" we need to get a total order on the whole set is compatible orders on all subsets of size 3.